# os.File.SetReadDealine: file type does not support deadline

Tags: windows, go

I use win10 and go1.11 windows/amd64

```
deviceid, err := getdeviceid(config.PlatformSpecificParams.ComponentID)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

path := "\\\\.\\Global\\" + deviceid + ".tap"
pathp, err := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(path)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

fileFd, err := syscall.CreateFile(  pathp,
                                    syscall.GENERIC_READ|syscall.GENERIC_WRITE,
                                    uint32(syscall.FILE_SHARE_READ|syscall.FILE_SHARE_WRITE),
                                    nil,
                                    syscall.OPEN_EXISTING,
                                    syscall.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM|syscall.FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                                    0)
……

file := os.NewFile(uintptr(fileFd), "nic")

……

file.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(t))   //   [ERROR] file type does not support deadline
```

The error occurred in the last line: **file type does not support deadline**

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

for Go before 1.11 SetReadDeadline seems to be defined for TCP, UDP and Unix domain (aka named) sockets, not files

See https://golang.org/pkg/net

But it is introduced for use on files in 1.11 (sorry I missed this), see https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.SetReadDeadline

I don't see a non blocking flag in your CreateFile call?  I don't know how this works on MS Windows...maybe I am missing it.  Deadline needs this..maybe a possible cause?

Comment: go1.11 adds SetReadDeadline for os.File。